# Accessing an enum inside a struct in C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct test {
    enum en {
        zero, one
    } en;
} test;

int main(){
    test t;
    // t.en = test::one; <--  How can I accomplish this?
    return 0;
}
```

`test::one` is a `C++` syntax and won't compile in `C`.
Is it possible to access `en` from outside the struct in C?

I know I can use integers here like `t.en = 1;` but I'm trying to use enum values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, by simply writing the name defined.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct test {
 enum en{
    zero, one
 } en;
} test;

int main(){
 test t;
 t.en = one;
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Funny thing is this won't compile in C++ `'one' was not declared in this scope`. Would you know why it works in C but not in CPP? do structs not create a scope in C and do in CPP?

Comment: @Dan: because C and C++ are different languages.   Compiling C code as C++ is risky: some constructs are not portable, some C identifiers are reserved in C++ (`new`...), `void *` expressions no longer convert implicitly and more insidiously, some expressions evaluate differently (such as `sizeof('x')`).

Answer (score 4):

In C, a `struct` does not create a new namespace for types - the fact that you defined `enum en` within the body of the struct definition makes no difference, that tag name is visible to the remainder of the code in the program.  It's not "local" to the `struct` definition.  Same with a nested `struct` type - if declared with a tag, such as

```
struct foo {
  struct bar { ... };
  ...
};
```

`struct bar` is available for use outside of `struct foo`.

C defines four types of namespaces - one for all labels (disambiguated by the presence of a `goto` or `:`), one for all tag names (disambiguated by the presence of the `struct`, `union`, or `enum` keywords), one for `struct` and `union` member names (per `struct` or `union` definition - disambiguated by their presence in a `struct` or `union` type definition, or by the presence of a `.` or `->` member selection operator), and one for all other identifiers (variable names, external (function) names, typedef names, function parameter names, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Structure do not introduce a separate scope in C.

Note also that using `en` as both the `enum` tag and variable name is perfectly fine in C, but somewhat confusing in C++.

Here is a modified version that should compile as C and C++:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
#define SCOPED_ENUM(s,e) s::e
#else
#define SCOPED_ENUM(s,e) e
#endif

typedef struct test {
    enum en {
        zero, one
    } en;
} test;

int main() {
    test t;
    t.en = SCOPED_ENUM(test, one);
    return 0;
}
```